# Change Current Object of the DetailView in XAF

Tags: c#, xaf

in XAF I change the CurrentObject of a DetailView with this code :

((DetailView)this.View).CurrentObject = newObject;

When I try to save Object, it tries to save previous object too and validates rules for the previous object. Is there a way to save only the new object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able co call ObjectSpace.Rollback() to abandon the changes to the current object.

However, it would depend what you are trying to achieve, but changing the view's CurrentObject is generally not a good idea. A lot of the context (permissions, available actions, editor visibility , etc.) come from the current object. Better might be to create a separate ObjectSpace with Apllication.CreateObjectSpace() and to make whatever changes you need there.

As with all things DevExpress, the first place to ask is their [Support Center](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/)

Comment: I know that, changing the DetailView's CurrentObject is not a good idea, but I want to have an opportunity to update objects without returning the ListView, therefore I change the CurrentObject of the DetailView, do you have any advice?

Comment: As I suggest above, you should use a separate ObjectSpace.